# Hololens unity application: Import .fbx 3D model at runtime in

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm playing with Unity since 6 months, so i'm not an "expert".

I'm trying to develop an app by which is possible to select a 3D model (mechanical drawing in .fbx) from a list, import it and, by adding some components to the model, scale, rotate or move the model shown.

Moreover, while the application is running, the user should be able to copy and paste a new .fbx drawing to a specific folder and the application, by accessing that folder, should be able to open also the new file...

So the matter is: is there a way to import runtime an fbx file and instatiate it as game object?

Thank you for your help...

L

Comment: Was your problem solved? If so, please consider selecting the answer as the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Importing heavy files (such as *.fbx* ones -granted it depends on the model but still...-) at runtime is always an heavy operation. Since you said it was for an **app** I guess you're targeting mobile platform so I would not advise it.

By googling *"unity import fbx runtime"* you can access [this thread](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/fbx-mesh-importer-at-runtime.230787/) on Unity forum where someone did achieve this. However the asset isn't online anymore.

If you're looking for a standalone platform, you can always use 2 Unity programs to achieve this: one where you load an manipulate 3D objects and one where you import *.fbx* files. To do so you can have follow this order (or even use some batch to do so automatically):

- open app in editor's mode
- look for new *.fbx* file that haven't been converted on some folders
- copy files to Untiy project folder (this will import them automatically)
- once they're imported you can wrap them into [AssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) and use them in your viewer

*Hope this helps,*